# MongoDB alternatives for $expr in aggregation query for older Mongo versions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have Mongo version 3.4 and I'm trying to use a query, written for newer Mongo versions, and found that $mergeObjects isn't supported. I'm not sure what can be used instead.

I have created a Mongo playground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-mplhGT0WtI

It's the following that I need to rewrite but not sure how to.

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: {
          id: "$_id",
          name: "$name"
      },
      root: {
          $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT"
      },
      questions: {
          $push: "$questions"
      }
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way but one work around that comes to mind is using [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) and then checking that the array size is 1:

```
...

  {
    $addFields: {
      unionSize: {
        $size: {
          $setUnion: [
            [
              "$responses.questionId"
            ],
            [
              "$set.questions.id"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      unionSize: 1
    }
  }

...
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yOym0hWHdxW)

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the Mongo playground to use $addFields - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-mplhGT0WtI - but still got an issue with $mergeObjects.

Comment: Just change it to use `$last` or `$first` instead of `$mergeObjects`.

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to do that with one use of $mergeObjects but it's also being used to combine the following - {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$root",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  }

which I can't use $first or $last for - https://mongoplayground.net/p/O6USu8yhyfm

Comment: There's nothing to replace `$mergeObjects` you will just have to do it manually with `$addFields` https://mongoplayground.net/p/EARPKM1kAT4.